# R cleaning data frame to identify which columns don't have corresponding output columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-cleaning

I need to tidy my dataframe so that it has inputs (e.g. `A.1`, `B.1`, `C.1`, ...) on column `V1` and outputs (`abc` and `123`, `def` and `456`, ...) on columns `V2` and `V3` (these two columns always come in pairs). This is what I would like to look like:

```
df_clean <- data.frame(V1 = c("A.1", "B.1", "C.1", "D.1", "E.1", "F.1", "C.1", "E.1", "G.1", "H.1"),
                       V2 = c("abc", "def", NA, "ghi", NA, NA, NA, NA, "jkl", "mno"),
                       V3 = c("123", "456", NA, "789", NA, NA, NA, NA, "101", "112"))
```

But right now it looks like below.

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c("A.1", NA, "B.1", NA, "C.1", NA, NA, "E.1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "H.1"),
             V2 = c(NA, "abc", NA, "def", NA, "D.1", "ghi", NA, "F.1", "C.1", "E.1", "G.1", "jkl", "mno"),
             V3 = c(NA, "123", NA, "456", NA, NA, "789", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "101", "112"))
```

To elaborate, you can see from the first four rows of `df` that if I have consecutive inputs that have outputs, the inputs will be on the first column and the outputs will be on the second and third column. But if there is an input with no output (like `C.1`), the next input (`D.1`) is placed at the second column, and the following inputs will continue to be placed there until an input with an output appears (e.g. after `D.1`, `ghi` `789` are on the second and third columns. Because `D.1` had outputs, `E.1` is placed back at the first column. But  `E.1` doesn't have an output, so `F.1` is now on the second column. `F.1` doesn't have an output either, so the next input (`D.1`) is also on the second column. When we get to `G.1`, it has an output so `jkl` and `101` are on the second and third column. Then `H.1` goes back on the first column.)

I've thought about combining `V2` and `V3` but this doesn't work if my input is in `V2`. I think I can identify the inputs since they all have the `.1` string at the end in common but hasn't gotten much further beyond this. Any suggestions on how to clean this dataframe up?

Comment: How did you load the data? Could you load it in a way that was closer to what you want? (or we could maybe help you). What you're asking for is probably possible, but will probably be very prone break at some point.

Comment: @harre This was an output from a linux script, which I have even less experience with and have zero idea how to fix. I figured I at least have a bit more experience with R and has been trying some things out before posting here (didn't post the details but am happy to share what I tried out so far) , but I hit a roadblock after a few hours and wanted to see if anyone could suggest a package or suggest some function I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`/`tidyr` you could do something like this:

```r
df |>
    # Move the V2's to V1 where ness.
    mutate(V1_old = V1,
           V1 = if_else(is.na(V1_old) & is.na(V3), V2, V1_old),
           V2 = if_else(is.na(V1_old) & is.na(V3), NA_character_, V2)) |>
    select(-V1_old) |>
    # Fill NA's, for V1, down
    fill(V1, .direction = "down") |>
    # Fill NA's within groups V1, for V2 + V3, up
    group_by(V1) |>
      fill(-V1, .direction = "up") |>
      # Filter away only duplicates for columns without NA's
      # If that's a mistake, use distinct() instead
      filter(is.na(V2) | !duplicated(cur_data())) |>
    ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   V1    V2    V3   
   <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 A.1   abc   123  
 2 B.1   def   456  
 3 C.1   NA    NA   
 4 D.1   ghi   789  
 5 E.1   NA    NA   
 6 F.1   NA    NA   
 7 C.1   NA    NA   
 8 E.1   NA    NA   
 9 G.1   jkl   101  
10 H.1   mno   112
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more suggestion:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(V1 = coalesce(V1, V2),
         V1 = if_else(str_detect(V1, "\\w\\.\\d+"), V1, NA_character_),
         V2 = coalesce(V2, V1),
         V2 = if_else(is.na(V3), NA_character_, V2)) %>% 
  fill(V1, .direction = "down") %>% 
  group_by(x = cumsum(V1 != lag(V1, def = first(V1)))) %>% 
  arrange(desc(row_number()), .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(1,2,3)
```

```
   V1    V2    V3   
   <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 A.1   abc   123  
 2 B.1   def   456  
 3 C.1   NA    NA   
 4 D.1   ghi   789  
 5 E.1   NA    NA   
 6 F.1   NA    NA   
 7 C.1   NA    NA   
 8 E.1   NA    NA   
 9 G.1   jkl   101  
10 H.1   mno   112
```